# R: How can I subset a list via array notation without declaring it?

Tags: r, arrays, subset

As an example of what I'm after, suppose that I want every multiple of 3 in the list of numbers from 1 to 100. The easier way that I know of doing this is as follows:

```
all<-1:100  
mod3<-all[all%%3==0]
```

Is there a way to do this without the first line? It seems silly that I have to declare a list (and therefore give it a name) before I can subset it. I could call the `subset` function, but the array notation in my second line comes so naturally that it would be a shame to not use it. In an ideal world, I'd call something like `1:100[1:100%%3==0]` but that obviously gives errors. Referring only to things that are built-in to R, what are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could wrap within brackets to make it a self-contained block as there is precedence for different operators

```
(1:100)[(1:100)%%3==0]
```

---

If the check the `?Syntax`, the different operator precedence are given

```
#:: ::: access variables in a namespace
#$ @    component / slot extraction
#[ [[   indexing
#^  exponentiation (right to left)
#- +    unary minus and plus
#:  sequence operator
#%any%  special operators (including %% and %/%)
#* /    multiply, divide
#...
```

In the above case, the expression within the `[]` works as expected because the `:` is above on the precedence wrt to `%%`.  But, it is the one outside having an issue because `[` is higher when compared to `:`

Comment: Beautiful! What should I have read that would've told me this?

Comment: @J.Mini it is in `?Syntax`