# Subset a list that is a function's output without declaring the output as a variable

Tags: r, list, subset

From the `gtools` library, take `combinations(5,2)`. This gives the following output:

```
> combinations(5,2)
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    2
 [2,]    1    3
 [3,]    1    4
 [4,]    1    5
 [5,]    2    3
 [6,]    2    4
 [7,]    2    5
 [8,]    3    4
 [9,]    3    5
[10,]    4    5
```

**Without declaring this output as a variable**, I wish to remove all of the elements from this output that have a value of 1 in the first column and return the resulting list in the same format as the original output.

So far, I have tried:

- Formulations similar to those suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61351988/10319707) answer. For example, `(combinations(5,2))[(combinations(5,2))[,1]>1]`. This gives what resembles the desired numbers, but the output is not an array. It appears to be a 1 dimensional vector of numbers.
- Removing the undesired outputs via a minus sign. For example, `(combinations(5,2))[-combinations(5,2)[,1]>1]`. This always returns `integer(0)`.
- The `subset` function. This always returns errors for me, usually complaining that one of my arguments isn't logical. I've tried to fix that by using `which`, but that hasn't helped.

What are my other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```r
combinations(5, 2)[combinations(5, 2)[, 1] > 1, ]
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    2    3
#> [2,]    2    4
#> [3,]    2    5
#> [4,]    3    4
#> [5,]    3    5
#> [6,]    4    5
```

though keep in mind that it does the `combinations` calculation twice.

The difference between this version and your first attempt is the comma after "> 1"

Answer (score 2):

If you use `magrittr` you can use

```
combinations(5,2) %>% .[.[,1]>1,]
```

this avoids the need to recalculate the expensive `combinations` calculation twice.

But why work so hard to avoid a vaariable? You end up doubling the memory used and calculating time. Are you opposed to writing a function as well? Why not

```
colFilter <- function(x, col, fun) x[fun(x[,col]),]
```

And then you can do

```
colFilter(combinations(5,2), 1, function(x) x>1)
```

which would be much more efficient.

Or a pipe line function would be

```
withX <- function(x, expr) eval(substitute(expr), list("."=x), parent.frame())
```

This allows you to write an expression where the value you pass in can be refered to by `.` in the the expression you wish to evaulate.

```
withX(combinations(5,2), .[.[,1]>1,])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
combinations(5,2)[combinations(5,2)[,1]!=1,]
```

It doesn't look very good but it works.